# Search for variable name using iloc function in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, loops

I have a pandas dataframe that consist of 5000 rows with different countries and emission data, and looks like the following:

| country | year | emissions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| peru | 2020 | 1000 |
|  | 2019 | 900 |
|  | 2018 | 800 |

The country label is an index.

eg.        `df = emission.loc[['peru']]`

would give me a new dataframe consisting only of the emission data attached to peru.
My goal is to use a variable name instead of 'peru' and store the country-specific emission data into a new dataframe.

what I search for is a code that would work the same way as the code below:

```
country = 'zanzibar'

df = emissions.loc[[{country}]]
```

From what I can tell the problem arises with the iloc function which does not accept variables as input. Is there a way I could circumvent this problem?

In other words I want to be able to create a new dataframe with country specific emission data, based on a variable that matches one of the countries in my `emission.index()`all without having to change anything but the given variable.

One way could be to iterate through or maybe create a function in some way?
Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: You can use this: `country = 'zanzibar' df = emissions.loc[[country]]`

Comment: I think you are confusing `loc` and `iloc`. Try using `df = emissions.loc[[country]]` which should work assuming the country names are the index of your original dataframe.

Comment: `emissions.loc[country]` will also work

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help guys. I see that I had a spelling error that sent me in the wrong direction from the start, working like a charm now. Probably wise to call this project a quit for today :)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach where you dont use a country name for your index:

```
emissions = pd.DataFrame({'Country' : ['Peru', 'Peru', 'Peru', 'Chile', 'Chile', 'Chile'], "Year" : [2021,2020,2019,2021,2020,2019], 'Emissions' : [100,200,400,300,200,100]})
country = 'Peru'
```

Then to filter:

```
df = emissions[emissions.Country == country]
```

or

```
df = emissions.loc[emissions.Country == country]
```

Giving:

```
   Country  Year  Emissions
0  Peru     2021  100
1  Peru     2020  200
2  Peru     2019  400
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to select by a certain string for your index. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4]}, index=['Peru','Peru','zanzibar','zanzibar'])
country = 'zanzibar'
df.loc[{country}]
```

This will return:

```
          a
zanzibar  3
zanzibar  4
```

In your case, removing one set of square brackets should work:

```
country = 'zanzibar'
df = emissions.loc[{country}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this solution is the same as your question. In this case I will give the solution to make a country name into a variable

But, because a variable name can't be named by space (" ") character, you have to replace the space character to underscore ("_") character.

*(Just in case your 'country' values have some country names using more than one word)*

Example:

- the United Kingdom to United_Kingdom

by using this code:

```
df['country'] = df['country'].replace(' ', '_', regex=True)
```

So after your country names changed to a new format, you can get all the country names to a list from the dataframe using `.unique()` and you can store it to a new variable by this code:

```
country_name = df['country'].unique()
```

After doing that code, all the unique values in 'country' columns are stored to a list variable called 'country_name'

Next,

Use `for` to make an iteration to generate a new variable by country name using this code:

```
for i in country_name:
    locals()[i] = df[df['country']=="%s" %(i)]
```

So, `locals()` here is to used to transform string format to a non-string format (because in 'country_name' list is filled by country name in string format) and `df[df['country']=="%s" %(i)]` is used to subset the dataframe by condition country = each unique values from 'country_name'.

After that, it already made a new variable for each country name in 'country' columns.

Hopefully this can help to solve your problem.